# Can we query with _id object on mongodb with mongoClient

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to query on mongodb with _id field

I am doing it like this

1st way:

```
 MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoDatabaseName);
            
FindIterable<MyEntity> iterable =    
 mongoDatabase.getCollection(tablename).find(eq("_id",
             agentId), MyEntity.class);

iterable.getFirst();   // Thats always null
```

2nd way:

```
Document document =    
mongoDatabase.getCollection(tableName).find(eq("_id", new 
 ObjectId(agentId))).first();
```

with 2nd way , document is there ,but then i am not able to change it to my Entity , I tried with converting from json with jackson , but then it gives error because in my entity there is "id" not "_id" and thats a string , not object.

Can i get some hint please.

Comment: Why did you use `agentId` in the first, but `id` in the second?

Comment: using the same , just wrote wrong in stackoverflow ,So i am using agentId in both , but not working

Comment: what does agentId contain?